# Regular Expression for SKU validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I do not know if this is nonsense but I need a regular expression to validate the **SKU** of a product, taking into account that it must be 10 characters minimum and 20 maximum and allow `[0-9]` and `[a-zA-Z]` but I have not the slightest idea, the regular expression is to be used from Javascript with `. test()`, any help?

Comment: Have you tried anything? You should learn at least [the basics of regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info), then give it a shot.

Comment: [As per FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):  _"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. **Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results**. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a service for regex is helpful.

This should be what you need 
`^[a-z0-9A-Z]{10,20}$`
if it is just JavaScript you can set a flag for upper and lower case
`/^[a-z0-9]{10,20}$/i`
Example below.

http://regex101.com/r/uE8fH1

Answer (score 3):

You can use character class and specify length range for this.

A character class is a set of characters (or character range) enclosed in a pair of square brackets like `[abc]` or `[A-Z]`.

So for your case, it would be `[A-Za-z\d]` which denotes an upper case or lower case letter or a digit. `\d` stands for digit.

For allowing n occurrence of any pattern, you can use `<your_pattern>{n}`. If it is a range from m to n, use `<your_pattern>{m,n}`. For specifying only minimum, use `<your_pattern>{n,}` and for specifying only maximum, use `<your_pattern>{,n}`.